# Database user tables and permissions

Tags: database, oracle, jsp

I'm making a db system project for college that requires online log-in for people to read information on their payments. I have a "person" table that stores information on people, and they have a unique identifier that will be their user name, with the password being generated somewhere else (given how the system works, this part represents no problem at all). However, sometimes some people won't be directly involved in the data inside the database, and instead they will have a password granted to them that will be stored inside the database.

Now. How do I assign "roles" to these users stored inside the database? By the way I'm working with Oracle and JSP as my host language.

Comment: Are you asking about Oracle database roles and privileges, or some type of user application role structure?

Comment: Both. How do db roles correlate to actual user roles? Or, how do I make a user application role structure? I'm a bit lost here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have to either

- use Oracle's native support for roles,
- store the data you need in a table, or
- derive it from something you have available outside the database.

For native support, see, for example, [docs.oracle.com](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96521/privs.htm#14881) for CREATE ROLE.

For storing the data you need in a table, you might be able to use something as simple as

```
create table user_roles (
  user_id integer primary key references users (user_id),
  user_role varchar(20) not null references user_roles (user_role)
);
```

If you do that, pay close attention to permissions on that table. You don't want users to be able to escalate their role.

For deriving it from something outside the database, you might be able to use something like

- network login name,
- IP address,
- cookie, or
- something else.

I'd be a little surprised if any of those work well, though. Most of them will probably require storing something in the database, too.

When I need roles within a database application, I usually rely on CREATE ROLE.

Comment: So, db roles are the solution. But how do I assign these roles to the users, and moreover, how do I display my users certain options in the system?

Comment: If I were you, I'd start with [Administering User Accounts and Security](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28301/users_secure.htm#ADMQS12040). Once you understand the concepts, talk to your coworkers about what avenues are open to you.

Comment: Oh, you're talking about coworkers. I don't have and that's why I'm a bit confused, since I know some basics about db security and it has nothing to do with front-end user administration, but rather with what kind of person works with the database.